# How to connect view button / label to controller file in Xcode 11?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode11

[image]Hey guys I have an strange problem. I recently updated to Xcode 11 and when I want to open the view controller file beside my storyboard file to connect IBAction for a button there is no button in Xcode to do so. There used to be a double circle button (similar to AUB picture) but I can't find it now.

I searched the web but couldn't find any solution either.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56675698/show-assistant-editor-missing-in-xcode-11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xcode 11 you will have open the ViewController.xib first, then hold OPTION (ALT) and click on the related ViewController.swift

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a new tab by clicking the button i circled in the image:
[image]